# $A \cap B = A \iff A \in P(B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$A$ and $B$ are two arbitrary sets and $P(B)$ is the power set of B.

Proof :
$$A \cap B   =  A$$
$$ \iff $$ $$ (\forall x) (x \in A \implies x \in A\cap B \implies x \in B)$$
$$ \iff $$ $$ A \subseteq B $$
$$ \iff $$ $$ A \in P(B) $$

The last step follows from the definition of the power set. $\square$

I cannot convenience myself about the correctness of the proof.

Comment: The proof is correct!

Comment: Hmmm, I think I'd like line to be more explicitly spelled out.  I could be wrong but to me it reads as "It's obvious that $A\cap B =A \iff A\subset B$".  I'd state more $A\cap B=A\implies \forall x\in A; x\in A\cap B$ so $x\in B$ and so so $A\subset B$.  While if $A\subset B$ implies $x\in A \iff x\in A$ and $x\in B\iff x\in A\cap B$ so $A=A\cap B$.  If feel by pinning yourself between if and only ifs you pulled the sheets too tight.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @fleablood Interesting point, I think you are correct at what you are saying about if and only ifs. What you have written does seem to be simpler than I have.

Comment: This almost gets down to matters of style but nearly one half and maybe more of the proof is a matter of definitions, so I'd prefer a proof that dust those away first. Something like:  $A\in P(B)$ is synonymous to $A\subset B$ so it is sufficient (and nesc) to proof $A\cap B =A \iff A\sub B$.  Then how you prove that is up to you and if you wish to prove it efficiently in a single line of if and only ifs you probably can.  I'd do it bidirectionally though. $A\cap B=A$ means $A$ consists only of elements that are in both $A$ and $B$. But that means all elements of $A$ are elements of $B$ so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A\in B$ in your line of proof is wrong.

$A\cap B=A\implies (\forall x)(x\in A\implies x\in A\cap B\implies x\in B\\\implies A\subset B\implies A\in P(B))$

Answer (score 2):

An easier way...

$$A \cap B   =  A \Rightarrow A \subseteq B \Rightarrow A \in P(B).$$